# Generating OpenAPI definitions and documentation for an existing flask project

Tags: api, flask, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to integrate an existing flask app with OpenAPI (Swagger), to generate its documentation and use Swagger UI. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution (expected behaviour with least changes) for me was to use connexion, and use OpenAPI Specifications to replace the routes layer. Instead of using Flask "directly", a connection app was created.

```
app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='swagger/')
app.add_api('my_api.yaml')
app.run(port=8080)
```

https://github.com/zalando/connexion